# Subtraction between two lists

Tags: list, subtraction

Suppose I have two lists:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[5,4,20],[9,100,7]]
y = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
```

I am trying  to get `z = x - y` so that my array should be like

```
z = [[0, 1, 2], [4, 3, 19], [8, 99, 6]]
```

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: -1. No effort to solve one's own problem.

Answer (score -1):

For example in Java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] x = new int[][]{
                {1,2,3},
                {5,4,20},
                {9,100,7}
            };
    int[][] y = new int[][]{
            {1,1,1},
            {1,1,1},
            {1,1,1}
        };

    int[][] result = new int[3][3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            result[i][j] = x[i][j] - y[i][j];
            System.out.print(result[i][j]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.print(" | ");
    }

}
```

}